# Редирект зарегистрированного пользователя со страницы регистрации в личный кабинет

Tags: php, авторизация, аутентификация

Привет!

Меня интересует, как происходит аутентификация и редирект зарегистрированных пользователей при обращении к главной странице.

Сценарий:

1. пользователь вбивает хттп://mysite и попадает на форму регистрации
2. пользователь прошел регистрацию и попал в свой личный кабинет, например: хттп://mysite/mycab.php
3. пользователь закрыл браузер, пошел погулял и ему опять нужно на сайт зайти, он вбивает хттп://mysite и **???**

Как сделать так, чтобы он **сразу** попал на хттп://mysite/mycab.php

Использую авторизацию основанную на cookies.

Судя по всему, при загрузке где-то на странице с формой надо куки проверять. Раньше с этим не работал, т.ч. надеюсь на помощь. Спасибо!

Comment: if (залогинен) { header('Location: хттп://mysite/mycab.php') }

Comment: @Invision, и `exit` забыли :Р

Comment: @Invision, Спасибо! А как вот это "залогинен" проверить? И header в какой части должен располагаться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В двух словах, это можно сделать 2мя способами:

1. с помощью JS
2. с помощью php

По сути каждый решает сам, как это удобнее делать.
Из-за того, что никакого кода не предоставлено, могу ответить только сугубо теоретически

1. вариант `РНР`: При обращении на страницу `index.php`, после того, как делаеться `session_start` делаеться проверка на установленную `cookie` в которой содержиться идентификатор пользователя. И если он есть - делаеться `<?php header('Location: хттп://mysite/mycab.php'); exit(); ?>`
2. вариант с `JS` : смысл тот же, но проверка идет на стороне клиента. И просто делаеться там де и редирект. НО! валидация все равно должна быть на стороне сервера и проверка существования пользователя в БД.